# R: z-score normalization

Tags: r, matrix, normalization

I´d like to z-score normalize each row of a matrix in R. I use the normalize-function which works fine for this purpose:

```
library(som)

training <- matrix(seq(1:20), ncol = 10)
training
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17    19
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
training_zscore <- normalize(training, byrow=TRUE)
training_zscore
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
[2,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
```

Lets assume that I now have another matrix e.g. the following:

```
validation <- matrix(seq(1:20)*2, ncol = 10)
validation
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    6   10   14   18   22   26   30   34    38
[2,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
```

I´d also like to z-score transform this new matrix. However the scaling should be identical to the training z-score matrix. How can I achieve this?

If I´d just perform seperate z-score normalization I´d get the following output:

```
> validation_zscore <- normalize(validation, byrow=TRUE)
> validation_zscore
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
[2,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
```

This is however not what I want e.g. in the training matrix the value "10" was transformed into a z-score of "-0.1651446". This should also be the case in the validation matrix (here 10 was however converted into a z-score of "-0.8257228"):

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're normalizing by row. Do you want the first row of `validation` to be normalized according to the first of `training`, and so on? If so, then you're not going to get 10 as -0.165 because these are different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear, but I assume you want each row of `validation` to be normalized using `training` as a "reference". If so, you can use `base::scale`  and give the numeric values of mean and standard deviation. What's the point of using `som::normalize`, anyway?

```
training <- matrix(seq(1:20), ncol = 10)
training_zscore <- t(scale(t(training)))
training_zscore
# [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
# [1,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
# [2,] -1.486301 -1.156012 -0.8257228 -0.4954337 -0.1651446 0.1651446 0.4954337 0.8257228 1.156012 1.486301
# attr(,"scaled:center")
# [1] 10 11
# attr(,"scaled:scale")
# [1] 6.055301 6.055301

validation <- matrix(seq(1:20)*2, ncol = 10)    
validation_zscore <- t(scale(t(validation), center = rowMeans(training),
                             scale = apply(training, 1, sd)))
# [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
# [1,] -1.321157 -0.6605783 0.0000000 0.6605783 1.321157 1.981735 2.642313 3.302891 3.963470 4.624048
# [2,] -1.156012 -0.4954337 0.1651446 0.8257228 1.486301 2.146879 2.807458 3.468036 4.128614 4.789192
# attr(,"scaled:center")
# [1] 10 11
# attr(,"scaled:scale")
# [1] 6.055301 6.055301
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for!